# node.js replace regex special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, replace

I'm cleaning up filenames, e.g.

from

`zx5-565x372.jpg?642e0d`

to

`zx5-565x372.jpg`

Specifically, I want to remove the `?` followed by 6 lowercase alphanumeric characters.

I've tried regex like

```
modified = original.replace("\?\w{6}", "")
```

where `\w` is same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and `{6}` is 6 of the same but with no joy.

Could someone kindly show me the right way?

Comment: why not just something like that: \?(.*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a string, not a RegExp.

```
var modified = original.replace(/\?\w{6}$/, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
modified = original.replace("\?\w{6}", "")
                            \_______/
```

This is just a string literal, it's not matched as a regex pattern.
You are *literally* replacing the string `?w{6}` with an empty string (because escaped `?` and `w` have no special meaning).

Use regex literals instead:

```
modified = original.replace(/\?\w{6}/, "");
```

Or just loosen your regex requirements in case the format changes:

```
modified = original.replace(/\?.*/, "");
```